# I'm using socket.io client for swift, the connection created but while emitting messages there is ERCONNRESET in the node.js log

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

Initiated socket io manager in a shared singleton.
Added the handlers in the singleton.

Added methods to connect to socket - 
1. In AppDelegate method app will enter foreground
2. In view will appear method

Added the call disconnect -
1. AppDelegate method when app enters background
2. View will disappear method within the view controller

Emitted the message when the user sends the message.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Ravi if you want to run socket in all over then use appdelegate and singlton and first of all handler remove from singlton.

Comment: Hey @Arun Singh, thanks for the input. Could you elaborate the handler part. If possible do you have a snippet for the code. Would be great if you could share some insights on the code. Thanks!

Comment: @RaviJayaraman please share your code snippet of singlton and app delegate.